# Read config.properties file from normal Folder and NOT SrcFolder (Java)

Tags: java, maven

How can I read a config.properties file from a normal Folder in Maven.

I have the normal Maven structur with src/main/java where my code is. I also have another folder config where my config.properties file is.

Now to my Question. I want to access the config.properties with Instream but if I do this that way I got Null back. If I do the config.properties in a SrcFolder It works like a charm. So how do I do it?

I want to do this over Instream bc I use prop.get

[Structur of my Folders][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/669xT.png

My Code for the reading of my config.properties and I got Null as return.

````
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

// import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
// import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class PropertyManager {

    // private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PropertyManager.class);

    private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "config.properties";
    private Properties props = null;
    File file = new File("config\\config.properties");

    public PropertyManager() throws IOException {

        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("Neue config.propertie Datei wurde angelegt, mit standart Werte.");
            final FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write("input.file=Input\\\\berufe.csv");
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("Programm wurde beendet, bitte erneut ausführen");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("config.propertie Datei ist vorhanden.");
            loadProperties(PROPERTIES_FILE);
        }
    }

    private void loadProperties(String filename) throws IOException {

        props = new Properties();

        final ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

        try (InputStream instream = loader.getResourceAsStream(filename)) {

            if (instream == null) {
                System.out.println("Property Datei kann nicht geöffnet werden.");
                return;
            }

            try {
                props.load(instream);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error beim lesen der Property Datei");
                // logger.error("Error beim lesen der Property Datei");
            }

        }

    }

    public String getProperty(String name) {

        return props.getProperty(name);
    }
}```

In my config.propertie file are lines. It is not empty.
````

Comment: `Class#getResourceAsStream(String)` - if the `config.properties` in the `src/main/resources` directory.  If it's not (ie it's externalised), then you run into all the other issues related to finding and resources outside of the app context

Comment: but it works if I simply create a Srcfolder and not a normal folder then it works without any error and the Srcfolder does not need to be in the src/main/java

Comment: You're missing context.  If the file resides out side the app context (ie it's not embedded), then you can have issues, if the working directory is different from the location of the file (ie you run the app from a different directory), this is why it's encouraged to use embedded resources (for read only content).  For writable content, they should be place in "well known locations".  Each OS has different requirements for how this should be handled

Comment: Perhaps try: `final String fs = File.separator; File file = new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + fs + "config" + fs + "config.properties");`.

Comment: Still „java.lang.NullPointetException“

Answer (score 0):

Solution!

I need it to say that the PROPERTIES_FILE = „confog\confog.properties“ and try (InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(filename)